# Trabalho para relacionar tabelas

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Fala pessoal.

Estou desenvolvendo um portal voltado para musica, a ideia e dar toda informação necessária ao visitante sobre seu artista/banda favorito: como Foto da banda, Descrição , Website, Facebook e na página da mesma listar Uma grade com todas as notícias da mesma.

No desenvolvimento criei uma tabela tbl_post com os campos:

id | status | sessao | categoria | capa | titulo | url | conteudo | banda | video | data | visitas

id - único para cada post com auto increment 
status - 1 ou 0 para inativar ou não o post
sessao - mostra se é categoria ou sub-categoria
categoria - mostra a categoria
capa - a capa do post (THumbnail)
titulo - o titulo
url - a url amigável do post
conteudo - nem preciso dizer rsrs
banda - nome da banda
video - url do video
data - lançamento do post
visitas - conta as visitas

E também criei uma Tabela chamado tbl_banda e nela coloquei os seguintes campos:

id - id unico para capa banda com auto increment
vert - mostra o estilo musical
capa - capa da mesma
banda - nome da banda
url - url da página da banda
origem - coloco o País de Origem
facebook -
twitter - 
website - 
descricao - 
data -

É o seguinte pessoal. To quebrando a cabeça a algum tempo e pior ainda, sinto que é algo muito primário que estou fazendo errado.

Estou com problema em relacionar o post com a banda,quero que quando eu postar um post e escolher a banda no post.Que seja atualizado o post na devida pagina da banda. to sentindo que o campo banda na tabela post não será utilizado, seja qual for o meio usado.

Segue abaixo o código para atualizar o post, achem um modo de eu implementar a informação na tabela bandas através do atualizar post:

// Script em andamento//

```
            case 'post_atualiza':
    sleep(1);
    $postid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postid']);
    $c['titulo']    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['titulo']);
    $c['categoria'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['categoria']);

    //LE E RECUPERA A SESSAO
    $readSes = read('categorias',"WHERE id = '$c[categoria]'");
    if($readSes): foreach($readSes as $ses); endif;
    $c['sessao'] = $ses['sessao'];      
    $c['banda']     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['banda']);
    $c['video']     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['video']);
    $c['conteudo']  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['conteudo']);
    $c['cadastro']  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cadastro']);
    $c['status']    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']);
    $c['url'] = setUri($c['titulo']);
    $c['cadastro'] = formDate($c['cadastro']);
    $verificaURL = read('posts',"WHERE id != '$postid' AND url = '$c[url]'");
```

---

```
            aqui fica o script das imgs,desnecessário para o assunto                    
            ---------------------------------------------------------


    update('post',$c,"id = '$postid'");


break;
```

[image: Tabela Post]

[image: Tabela Bandas]

Comment: Você pode editar a sua pergunta e adicionar esses links. (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/16894/edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa de uma foreign key que relacione a tabela "tbl_post" com a tabela "tbl_banda". por exemplo:

1º -(Tabela) "tbl_banda" com o campo "idBanda (PK)"

2º -(Tabela) "tbl_post" com o campo "idPost" e "idBanda (FK)"

O relacionamento é de 1 para "n", ou seja, 1 banda para vários posts.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda,fico muito grato. Desculpe a demora para responder,estive tentando usar esse script no meu código, e agora que funcionou, estou aqui para agradecer, Um Abraço.